# An inequality involving the Möbius function deduced using the Steffensen's inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, analytic-number-theory, mobius-function

If there are no mistakes using the inequality of the right from the so-called Steffensen's inequality, see this [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteffensensInequality.html) or the book by Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, *Tables of Integrals, Series, and Products*, 6th ed. San Diego, Academic Press (2000) that is referenced, I can to write $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\frac{_1F_2\left(\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2},\frac{n}{2}+\frac{3}{2};-\frac{\pi^2}{16}\right)}{n+1}\leq \frac{2}{\pi}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n(n+1)}\right),\tag{1}$$ where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function.

> **Question.** Can you prove that $(1)$ is true (without using the mentioned inequality)? **Many thanks.**

These are some codes that I've computed with Wolfram Alpha online calculator

`plot sum mu(n)/n x^n, from n=1 to 1000, for 0<x<1`

`int cos(pi/2 x)x^n dx, from x=0 to 1`

and all issues works thanks to the uniform convergence.

*The motivation* of this question is try to combine functions defined involving the Möbius function with integral inequalities as previous (or well with the Stolarsky's Inequality) with the purpose to state some interesting facts about the Möbius function or its means, if it is feasible.

Comment: Feel free if you want to criticize in comments if my idea/motivation is potentially interesting,

Comment: How did you manage to prove the non-negativity of the involved functions?

Comment: I don't know I did the plot of the function involving the Möbius function  @JackD'Aurizio

Comment: That is just saying RH holds because it looks so...

Comment: I'm sorry, I tell you the truth @JackD'Aurizio